# How to un-high-lite block of text in VI

Tags: ubuntu, vim, vi

Sorry if this makes little sense.  I honestly do not know what I do to cause it, but I do something.  I've googled on this but haven't found a solution to this.  I am using VI on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have been trying to learn and use VI for a while now.  One gotcha that happens to me every once in a while is I unintentionally high-light a block of code.  It looks exactly like I somehow entered visual mode and selected the block all in one instant. Usually it is about 10 to 20 lines become high-lighted all at once.  I do not know what key strokes I'm hitting to cause this.

Problem is I do not know how to un-high-light the area and I get fearful I may affect some change that I cannot undo with 'u'.  I've tried 'y' as in copy, but the area stays high-lighted.

Any ideas on what this is, what I may be keying in to cause it and MOSTLY, how to un-high-light the area?

Thanks much!

Comment: Press Esc or Ctrl+C is not enough to quit the mode ?

Perhaps the mouse triggers this or a key triggering a ctrl+v ?

Comment: usually `ESC` will bring you back. do you use someone else's vimrc without understanding what it does? can you reproduce it without loading your vimrc?

Comment: Are you running vim in the terminal? It sounds like you just highlighted text in the console .. which really has no effect on vim at all. Next time it happens, do something .. like hit `d`. If the text disappears, hit `u` to undo and you know it's vim. If nothing happens, it's just drag-over highlighting in the terminal.

Comment: Orel and Kent: Sorry, crazy busy.  I've tried Esc and Ctr+C.   Kent: Yes to running vi in the terminal.  I will look for the 'drag-over' highlighting.  I'm trying to catch what I'm doing when it happens, but of course it never does when I'm thinking on it.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
:noh
```

command? This stands for "no highlight search"